# Json mesclarar com Array em Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Gostaria de saber (entender) como tratar um json em javascript do tipo:

```
var arrDados = {"mes":["12","5","1"], "mes":["2","8","3"]};
var meses = {1:'Jan', 12:'Dez', 6:'Junho', 5:'Abril', 3:'Março', 8:'Agosto', 2:'Fevereiro'}
```

A ideia é que conforme o índice MES e seu Array de números onde cada um indica um mês

12 => Dezembro
3 => Marços

```
for (i in arrDados.mes) {
  indice = arrDados.mes[i];
    console.log(indice);
}
```

Assim to pegando só os valores do primeiro indice do json

detalhes:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho uma grid no sistema assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: `arrDados` tem chaves duplicadas... isso é sintaxe inválida. Tens a certeza que o JSON é mesmo assim? de onde vem esse JSON?

Comment: Olá @Sergio a priore eu coloquei daquele, mas eu terei vários Json assim: {"mes":["12","5","1"]}

{"mes":["10","3","2"] porém não sei bem como fazer.. vou mostrar uma imagem

Comment: Ok, queres dizer que essa variável será `var arrDados = [{"mes":["12","5","1"]}, {"mes":["2","8","3"]}];`?

Comment: é, creio que esse é o formato certo mesmo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu acredito que no seu caso vocẽ deve receber um array de objetos, que ficaria dessa forma...

```
var arrDados = [{"mes": ["12","5","1"]}, {"mes": ["2","8","3"]}];
var meses = {1:'Jan', 12:'Dez', 6:'Junho', 5:'Abril', 3:'Março', 8:'Agosto', 2:'Fevereiro'};

for (i of arrDados) {
    console.log('..........');
    for (m of i.mes) {
    console.log(meses[m]);
  }
}
console.log('..........');
```